# What does the stamp drop down menu in the render panel do?

Tags: rendering

I am working on a project right now, and during the render process I noticed a little check box that says stamp.
When I selected the drop down menu it had a bunch of selections the refer to text and font, and things like that.

My scene has text in it, and I was wondering what this section does, and how it is applicable to text scenes.

Comment: Note that in Blender 2.8 this has been moved to the _Metadata_ section of the _Output_ tab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *Stamp* section in the *Render* panel goal is used to draw some information on the render output. This can be useful for a work in progress production.

See the [blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Reference/Panels/Scene/Render/Stamp).

For example you can select *Frame* to print the current frame number on the final output.

The *Font size*, *Text color* and *Background* settings allow you to control how this information is displayed.

You can additionally print a custom note by checking the *Note* setting and writing whatever you want.

[image]

Comment: Great answer. It's also useful for profiling animations by checking the "RenderTime" check, which will print the amount of time it took to render that frame. I.e. render at 25% and see which frames are taking the longest.